# angular 1: image won't reload after a while

Tags: angularjs, image

In my HTML I have this img link:

**imgURL is set in the controller:**

```
$scope.imgURL = 'img/img_'+$scope.img.id+'.jpg;
```

With the first changes it works perfectly, but after a while the image doesn't show anymore..??

I read an tried several "solutions" like adding a parameter with random value so it forces to reload, but it didn't work. I log the url in the console and see it changing, so that's not the point.

What can cause the not appearing of the image after a while, it looks so random..? 
Your answer is highly appreciated, I'm rather desperate :-/

Comment: Please show us your code and share a fiddle.

Comment: Maybe you use one-time bindings in you template, like {{::imgURL}} ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about your HTML structure or code but with AngularJS I would do such a image source rotation with something like this. It's simple and works:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('mainController', function($scope, $interval) {

  var images = [
    'https://placehold.it/350x150',
    'https://placehold.it/450x250',
    'https://placehold.it/250x250'
  ];

  var i = 0;
  $scope.image = images[i];
  $interval(function() {
    i++;
    if (i < images.length) {
      $scope.image = images[i];
    } else {
      $scope.image = images[0];
      i = 0;
    }
  }, 3000, 0);

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainController">
  <img ng-src="{{image}}">
</body>

</html>
```

You can apply your image variable manipulation to this easily. The main part in the example above is to use `ng-src`.